# Node modules is not added in the folder after running yarn hardhat

Tags: solidity, blockchain, hardhat, smart-contract-wallets

Even after adding the hardhat packages by yarn multiple times, node modules are not showing in the folder.
[image]
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You should initialize the project before installing the packages.

This should be the order to install hardhat through yarn.

```
yarn init -y 
yarn add --dev hardhat 
npx hardhat
```

If it doesn't work, you can try install using the npm.

```
npm init -y
npm install --save-dev hardhat
npx hardhat
```

For more information you can click [here](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/guides/project-setup).

Tell me if it helps!

Comment: Thank you so much mate, it works now!!